# How cut a continuous skewed variable to exteremly high to extremly low categories?

Tags: r, variables, regression, categorical-data, cut

I have a continuous varaible in my dataset with such distribution:

```
summary(emissions$NMVOC_gram)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
       0      256      547    15802     1074 50818630
```

how can i categorize this variable to unequal levels of extremly high to extremly low, low, high and medium in R or excel?  i add what i should have as picture,

thank you for the help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRMBY.png)

I tried cut function in r but the result was not what i expected,actuallly i do not know how should i define the breaks, in my data the 3rd Qu. is lower than the Mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you want to cut data into quintiles (5 categories). Have included only count data than percentages.

```
library(tidyverse)
xs=quantile(iris$Sepal.Length,c(0,1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5,1))
xs2<-as.data.frame(xs)
iris <- iris %>%
  mutate(Sepal_legth_cat = cut(Sepal.Length, breaks=xs, labels=c(paste0("ext low"),
                                                                      paste0("low"),
                                                                      paste0("med"),
                                                                      paste0("high"),
                                                                      paste0("ext high"))))

ggplot(iris,aes(Sepal_legth_cat))+
  geom_bar()+
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: thank you for your comment, i tried but the code did not produce the graph that i added here, maybe because of very skewed data that i have, i only want to categorize this data which is emission (gram) to different categories.

Comment: emission data is not prebuilt in R. I have used iris data to illustrate the solution.

Comment: should I have the same breaks as you define in xs? the variable that i want to categorize has this distribution:        Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
       0      256      547    15802     1074 50818630

Comment: No you can change the breaks as you wish.Mean and median are measures of central tendency; i am not quite sure why u want to include both mean and median while categorizing. If you want to categorize into quartile : change to c(0,1/4,2/4,3/4,1)